# Processing dates into 'episodes' following a step-wise algorithm

Tags: sql, date, recursion, teradata

I have a table of patients of whom some have one or more 'events' (basically dates).  I need to process these dates into episodes using the following steps:-

> 1. Following an event, project forwards 14 days and use as a potential end-of-episode date.
>      a.  Events within this period are ignored, assumed related to the initial events.
> 2. If there are no events in the 14 days after the potential end-of-episode date, 
>      halt the algorithm - the episode has been fully identified.
> 3. If there is an event in the 14 days after the potential end-of-episode date, 
>      move potential end-of-episode date to new event date + 14 days.
> 4. Repeat from step 2 until there is 14 days from the end-of-episode date clear of events.;

Below is some test data.  The 'real' data is patid (patient identifier), eventdate and rn (a unique row number, reset to 1 for each patient, applied in date order).  Exp_end is my own entry to indicate the end date of episode.  It's on the row that would be the last event for the episode:-

```
"patid","rn", "eventdate",   "exp_end"
     1,   1,  01-01-2010,  14-01-2010
     1,   2,  11-02-2010,  24-02-2010
     2,   1,  01-01-2010,  
     2,   2,  07-01-2010,  
     2,   3,  12-01-2010,  14-01-2010
     2,   4,  21-02-2010,  06-03-2010
     3,   1,  01-01-2010,  
     3,   2,  12-01-2010,  
     3,   3,  24-01-2010,  06-02-2010
     3,   4,  21-02-2010,  06-03-2010
     4,   1,  01-01-2010,  
     4,   2,  24-01-2010,  
     4,   3,  28-01-2010,  
     4,   4,  04-02-2010,  17-02-2010
     4,   5,  21-02-2010,  06-03-2010
     5,   1,  26-02-2004,  10-03-2004
     5,   2,  03-09-2004,  
     5,   3,  09-09-2004,
     5,   4,  21-09-2004,  04-10-2004
     5,   5,  05-10-2004,
     5,   6,  14-10-2004,
     5,   7,  28-10-2004,  10-11-2004
```

The SQL code produces the same table:-

```
CREATE TABLE dp.ep( eventdate DATE FORMAT 'YY/MM/DD', exp_end DATE FORMAT 'YY/MM/DD', patid INTEGER, rn INTEGER) PRIMARY INDEX pats ( patid );
INSERT INTO db.ep (eventdate, exp_end, patid, rn) VALUES(TO_DATE('2010-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'), NULL, 2.0, 1.0);
INSERT INTO db.ep (eventdate, exp_end, patid, rn) VALUES(TO_DATE('2010-02-04','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2010-02-17','YYYY-MM-DD'), 4.0, 4.0);
INSERT INTO db.ep (eventdate, exp_end, patid, rn) VALUES(TO_DATE('2010-01-12','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2010-01-14','YYYY-MM-DD'), 2.0, 3.0);
INSERT INTO db.ep (eventdate, exp_end, patid, rn) VALUES(TO_DATE('2010-02-21','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2010-03-06','YYYY-MM-DD'), 3.0, 4.0);
INSERT INTO db.ep (eventdate, exp_end, patid, rn) VALUES(TO_DATE('2010-01-24','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2010-02-06','YYYY-MM-DD'), 3.0, 3.0);
INSERT INTO db.ep (eventdate, exp_end, patid, rn) VALUES(TO_DATE('2010-01-24','YYYY-MM-DD'), NULL, 4.0, 2.0);
INSERT INTO db.ep (eventdate, exp_end, patid, rn) VALUES(TO_DATE('2010-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'), NULL, 3.0, 1.0);
INSERT INTO db.ep (eventdate, exp_end, patid, rn) VALUES(TO_DATE('2010-02-11','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2010-02-24','YYYY-MM-DD'), 1.0, 2.0);
INSERT INTO db.ep (eventdate, exp_end, patid, rn) VALUES(TO_DATE('2010-02-21','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2010-03-06','YYYY-MM-DD'), 4.0, 5.0);
INSERT INTO db.ep (eventdate, exp_end, patid, rn) VALUES(TO_DATE('2010-01-07','YYYY-MM-DD'), NULL, 2.0, 2.0);
INSERT INTO db.ep (eventdate, exp_end, patid, rn) VALUES(TO_DATE('2010-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'), NULL, 4.0, 1.0);
INSERT INTO db.ep (eventdate, exp_end, patid, rn) VALUES(TO_DATE('2010-01-12','YYYY-MM-DD'), NULL, 3.0, 2.0);
INSERT INTO db.ep (eventdate, exp_end, patid, rn) VALUES(TO_DATE('2010-01-28','YYYY-MM-DD'), NULL, 4.0, 3.0);
INSERT INTO db.ep (eventdate, exp_end, patid, rn) VALUES(TO_DATE('2010-02-21','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2010-03-06','YYYY-MM-DD'), 2.0, 4.0);
INSERT INTO db.ep (eventdate, exp_end, patid, rn) VALUES(TO_DATE('2010-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2010-01-14','YYYY-MM-DD'), 1.0, 1.0);
INSERT INTO db.ep (eventdate, exp_end, patid, rn) VALUES(TO_DATE('2004-02-26','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2004-03-10','YYYY-MM-DD'), 5.0, 1.0);
INSERT INTO db.ep (eventdate, exp_end, patid, rn) VALUES(TO_DATE('2004-09-03','YYYY-MM-DD'), NULL, 5.0, 2.0);
INSERT INTO db.ep (eventdate, exp_end, patid, rn) VALUES(TO_DATE('2004-09-09','YYYY-MM-DD'), NULL, 5.0, 3.0);
INSERT INTO db.ep (eventdate, exp_end, patid, rn) VALUES(TO_DATE('2004-09-21','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2004-10-04','YYYY-MM-DD'), 5.0, 4.0);
INSERT INTO db.ep (eventdate, exp_end, patid, rn) VALUES(TO_DATE('2004-10-05','YYYY-MM-DD'), NULL, 5.0, 5.0);
INSERT INTO db.ep (eventdate, exp_end, patid, rn) VALUES(TO_DATE('2004-10-14','YYYY-MM-DD'), NULL, 5.0, 6.0);
INSERT INTO db.ep (eventdate, exp_end, patid, rn) VALUES(TO_DATE('2004-10-28','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2004-11-10','YYYY-MM-DD'), 5.0, 7.0);
```

Summarily, these are the results I'm hoping for:-

```
patid    epi_start       epi_end       epi_num

  1      01JAN2010      14JAN2010            1
         11FEB2010      24FEB2010            2


  2      01JAN2010      14JAN2010            1
         21FEB2010      06MAR2010            2


  3      01JAN2010      06FEB2010            1
         21FEB2010      06MAR2010            2


  4      01JAN2010      17FEB2010            1
         21FEB2010      06MAR2010            2

  5      26FEB2004      10MAR2004            1
         03SEP2004      04OCT2004            2
         05OCT2004      10NOV2004            3
```

( Of course, the help I need is getting to the table above - I can process further to get this type of output.)

I can get the results easily enough in SAS but with SQL, I'm tearing my hair out!  I imagine it needs recursive CTE SQL, something which I'm not great at...

I'm using Teradata SQL, by the way.

Any help will be great.

Comment: Not quite.  If there are events in day 14 - 28, I need to move the potential end of episode date to that event (+ 14 days).  And then if there's another event in that period, I need to include that, adding a further 14 days, etc...

Comment: `4,   2,  24-01-2010,` doesn't match your description, should this be `4,   2,  14-01-2010,`?

Comment: @dnoeth The 24-01-2010 row seems OK.  As it's 14-28 days after 01-01-2010, this means the new end-of episode date is now 24-01-2010 + days.  However, there's an event on the 28-01 - and another on the 04-02 - pushing the end-of-episode date to 04-02 + 14 days (=17-02-2010)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly your rules can be rephrased as following:

1. All rows within 4 weeks after the initial event (rn=1) belong to the first episode.
2. After 4 weeks a new episode only starts when the gap between the current and the previous row is greater than 2 weeks.

Now it's no longer an iterative algorithm. Of course this can be done using a Recursive CTE, but I prefer Windowed Aggregates :-)

This seems to return the correct result:

```
SELECT patid, 
   MIN(eventdate) AS epi_start, 
   CASE
      WHEN MAX(eventdate) > MIN(eventdate) + 13 -- more than two weeks since start
      THEN MAX(eventdate) + 13 -- adjust end to two weeks after latest date 
      ELSE MIN(eventdate) + 13 -- two weeks after start
   END AS epi_end, 
   epi_num
FROM
 (
   SELECT dt.*,
      SUM(new_epi) -- calculate the episode number 
      OVER (PARTITION BY patid 
            ORDER BY rn 
            ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) + 1 AS epi_num
   FROM
    (
      SELECT ep.*,
                   -- less than 4 weeks after the initial date
         CASE WHEN eventdate < MIN(eventdate) OVER (PARTITION BY patid) + 28
                   -- less than 2 weeks after the previous date
                OR eventdate < MAX(eventdate) -- previous date (equivalent to LAG(eventdate)
                                OVER (PARTITION BY patid 
                                      ORDER BY rn
                                      ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) + 14 
              THEN 0 -- same episode
              ELSE 1 -- new episode starts
         END AS new_epi       
      FROM ep 
    ) AS dt
 ) AS dt
GROUP BY patid, epi_num
ORDER BY 1,4
```

If `rn` is created by a `ROW_NUMBER` you might get rid of that calculation by using `ORDER BY eventdate` instead of `rn` (if it's unique per `patid`)

Edit:

I didn't get your logic correctly, it can't be simplified, so it can't be done with OLAP, you need a recursive approach:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte 
 (
   patid, 
   epi_start, 
   epi_end,
   potential_end,
   rn, 
   epi_num
 )
AS
 (
   SELECT patid, 
      eventdate AS epi_start, 
      eventdate + 13  AS epi_end,
      eventdate + 13 + 14 AS potential_end,
      rn, 
      CAST(1 AS SMALLINT) AS epi_num
   FROM ep
   WHERE rn = 1

   UNION ALL

   SELECT
      cte.patid,
      CASE WHEN ep.eventdate <= cte.epi_start + 13
           THEN cte.epi_start
           WHEN ep.eventdate <= cte.potential_end 
           THEN cte.epi_start
           ELSE ep.eventdate
      END AS epi_start_new,

      CASE WHEN ep.eventdate <= cte.epi_start + 13
           THEN cte.epi_end
           ELSE ep.eventdate + 13
      END AS epi_end_new,

      CASE WHEN ep.eventdate <= cte.epi_start + 13
           THEN cte.potential_end
           WHEN ep.eventdate <= cte.potential_end
           THEN ep.eventdate+ 13    
           ELSE ep.eventdate + 13 + 14
      END AS potential_end_new,  
      ep.rn,
      epi_num +
      CASE WHEN epi_start_new <> cte.epi_start THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM cte JOIN ep
     ON cte.patid = ep.patid
    AND cte.rn +1 = ep.rn
 ) 
SELECT patid, MIN(epi_start), MAX(epi_end), epi_num
FROM cte
GROUP BY patid, epi_num
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Comment: Wow, that's terrific. I would never have come up with that myself.  Indeed, it's so good it's highlighted problems with my SAS version ... (where dates meet each other, that sort of thing).  Thanks very much!

Comment: Ah, I spoke too soon!  I've added another example (patid: 5) for which the SQL doesn't quite work.  The SQL produces 2 episodes in October: 5Oct to 18Oct & 28Oct to 10Nov.  It should be 1 episode - 5Oct to 10Nov - as 28Oct is in the 14-28 day window from the 5Oct (step 3 above). The issue is with the innermost sql statement that classifies episodes.  Apologies for not having this type of example beforehand.  I will take a look and update the code if I can work it out.